# Eclipse workspace ? I have a problem when Eclipse start

Tags: eclipse, java-me, workspace

I have a problem with Eclipse. I use Eclipse on Linux to code J2ME program. I choose workspace different from default workspace, and I set eclipse show dialog to choose workspace every start. I create a J2ME project and run it, then close it when done. But when I re-start Eclipse, Eclipse don't show workspace diaglog ! It choose default workspace: /home/username/workspace ! I try re-start, re-install a lot, but it still not work right way. Somebody can help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to choose this in Windows > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces, and check "Prompt for workspace on startup"

EDIT : off course, if this does not work as expected, it's a bug, you can submit it...

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [Eclipse startup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343351/eclipse-startup-error/6361126#6361126). While Tristan has provided the best answer, you might also want to try this from the command line, from your Eclipse directory:

```
eclipse.exe -clean -showlocation -data "C:\<my workspace location>"
```

This will give you a clean start, will show the location of your workspace in the title bar, and will start from the workspace you specify.

Comment: I try use eclipse.exe -clean on Windows and it work fine. But why Eclipse don't fix this bug ? user fix manual that is not good. Any way to fix it ?

Comment: Follow what @Tristan said, Windows > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces, and check "Prompt for workspace on startup." You might also want to select your unused directory and use the "Remove" button. This works correctly on Helios, and I think it will work for you as well.

Comment: I have checked "Prompt for workspace on startup", but it's still don't work fine. I use Eclipse Indigo, and install CDT and more plugin.

Comment: Once you check "Prompt for workspace on startup," press Apply, and exit, you should start eclipse.exe by itself. (No -clean or -data). If you don't get prompted, then please report your problem at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/. I just checked there and did not see your problem.

Comment: If I first use -clean argument, then I check it and restart Eclipse, I show me workspace dialog. But if I open a project and run it, and restart, workspace dialog disappear again. Only use -clean, Eclipse run fine.

Comment: I checked this on Indigo but on Windows. It is working correctly. It is unlikely that the feature is working on Windows but the same code is not working on Linux. It is possible that one of your plugins is interfering with normal use. Maybe you could try starting with no plugins?