# M2Eclipse crashes Eclipse: java heap space

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have installed M2Eclipse plugin for maven , but after installing plugin when i tried to proceed then eclipse shows error's and get crashed,slow or hanged.

It shows following error : Background Indexer Crash Recovery
                                              java heap space .. and many more similar exceptions.

I have increased heap size in eclipse.ini  file but this issue was not get solved. I have also increased heap space using command : java -Xms -Xmx through  command line ,still its not working.

Comment: Does Maven call on command line work?

Comment: You might get more info if you provide more info - precisely what the exceptions said, and exactly how you tried to increase the heap size in eclipse.ini.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse startup error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343351/eclipse-startup-error)

Answer (score 5):

set eclipse.ini

> ```
> -Xms512m
> -Xmx1024m
> ```

solved my m2eclipse retrieving prototype problem

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, but, it's not working to increase the heap space. So, I created a new workspace, amazing, everything was normal: I could see the archetypes list again. I guessed something wrong with the m2eclipse plugin, So, I deleted the folders that whoes name contains characters 'm2e' in the path 'workspace.metadata.plugins'. And then, I restarted the eclipse, everything returned to normal.The problem has been solved.

Comment: I had the same issue.  The m2 trees will be recreated, so no worry here.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse.ini, I changed

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms40m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

to

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

In other words, I raised the initial heap size. That resolved it for me.  My allowed heap size when actually running Eclipse Indigo rose from 64 MB to 169 MB

Answer (score 0):

I did all of the above, to no change - 
I ended up just creating a new workspace! And everything went back to normal ..

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked by change 
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m