# Java eclipse unable to use

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have installed java18.0.1 and unable to run eclipse due to following 2 errors.My idea is learning selenium. pls help as im stuck.[image]

one error mentioned below in pic other is "out of memory error occured.consult eclipse readme. see .log file for more warning.you want to exit workbech/?

Comment: maybe you can find proper answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244479/m2eclipse-crashes-eclipse-java-heap-space

Comment: Does running Eclipse with an embedded Java 17 help? In _Help > Install New Software..._ work with [`https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release/l‌​atest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/17/updates/release/l‌​atest/) and install _JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE **Complete**_.